# Session not working on wamp but works on live server

Tags: php, session, wamp

I have this code and I have tried everything i can think of to get it to work on my WAMP local server any help would be greatly appreciated. I am PHP stupid. This works on a live server but not my WAMP server. I do get logged in just the pages do not seem to be passing the session variable to the proper user level. That's what's not working sorry for the poor description the first time.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['login']))
 {
if ($level == "Administrator") {

echo 'My Content';
}

elseif ($level == "Bank Officer") {
echo "";
}

elseif ($level == "Agent") {
echo "";
 }

elseif(!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$password = $_POST['password'];


$checklevel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '".$login."' AND password = '".$password."' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($checklevel) == 1)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklevel);
    $level = $row['level'];
    $_SESSION['level'] = $level;
}

$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '".$login."' AND password = '".$password."' AND level='".$level."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $login = $row['login'];
    $agent = $row['agent'];
    $_SESSION['agent'] = $agent;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
```

Thanks you for any help at all.

Comment: and not working means? page isn't displaying?

Comment: btw you have multiple SQL injection vulnerabilities in the code among other potential security issues. Sanitize ALL your $_POST data before passing them to an SQL query or assigning them as a value to a $_SESSION variable. Also do no use mysql_*() function as they will be deprecated and are not secure or reliable to use. Instead use PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_SESSION['level'] == "Bank Officer") 
{
    header('Location: index3.php'); 
    exit;
}
elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == "Agent")
{
    header('Location: index4.php'); 
    exit;
}
elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == "Bank Manager") 
{
    header('Location: index5.php'); 
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "Contact Administrator";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I have an include file that has session_start() for this code this is on more than one page. Yes the page does not load for any of the pages this is on. Also I don't know what you mean here Sanitize ALL your $_POST data before passing them to an SQL query or assigning them as a value to a $_SESSION variable. "Also do no use mysql_*() function as they will be deprecated and are not secure or reliable to use. Instead use PDO or MySQLi"

Comment: Please update your question by including ALL PHP code and files that are processed, included, etc before that code. We can't help you if you don't provide us with what we need. If you had stated you were including other files then the answer provided would have been different. Please help us help you by providing as much information to us such that we can accurately debug it for you.

Comment: try the above edit, you were checking $level's value not $_SESSION['level']

Comment: Thanks cryptic that fixed that problem you are the man now I have new problem. On main index it is suppose to use separate header that is in another file can you tell me what's wrong with this line of code. "if ($_SESSION['level'] == "Agent") echo header('Location: index4.php');"

Comment: If you mean header as in header template then that code wont work since it is setting an HTTP header to do a browser redirect to index4.php. I assume you want to change that to the following:

Comment: ($_SESSION['level'] == "Agent") include 'index4.php';

Comment: I am sorry for n ot being clear I am trying to get it to redirect to that index4.php n ot include it? Thanks for your help it is not redirecting it?

Comment: ($_SESSION['level'] == "Agent") header('Location: index4.php'); exit;

Comment: remove the echo and make sure to put exit; after any header redirect otherwise PHP will continue to process rest of script, and an attacker can ignore the redirect and acquire access to script still.

Comment: This might help this is all the if else code for this. if ($_SESSION['level'] == "Bank Officer") echo header('Location: index3.php');
elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == "Agent")header('Location: index4.php');
elseif ($_SESSION['level'] == "Bank Manager") echo header('Location: index5.php');
else "Contact Administrator";

Comment: edited answer, please put ALL curly { or } braces all the time.

Comment: I am sorry cryptic this part is working like I have it I had deleted out the agent I put in there by mistake. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP YOU HAVE BEEN GREAT. THANKS

Comment: exit() also solved my problem. Live server didn't complain about this but wamp did. So exit() after every header(Location...) line was the cure.